# Array.lenght returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wish to get the length of an array so I can use it further in another function but it returns undefined. This piece of code gets a file, opens it and splits it for each new line. I'm trying to get the length of the array but returns undefined.

```
function readBatFile(bfile){
    var rawFile1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile1.open("GET", bfile, false);
    rawFile1.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile1.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile1.status === 200 || rawFile.status === 0)
            {
                var allCode = rawFile1.responseText;
                var ary = new Array;
                ary = allCode.split(/.*\n/gm);
                var rcount = ary.lenght;
                document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = rcount;

            }
        }
    };
    rawFile1.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Check the typo. `length` it is..

Comment: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is spelled length not lenght.

It should be:

```
var rcount = ary.length;
```

Comment: That was one of the problems couldn't see it 10x